# Set permissions on an item depending on column value

Tags: permissions, wss-3.0, splistitem, groups

Is there anyway to set permissions on an item depending on a column value? I was think about creating a feature to do this but do I have to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you will need a custom solution for this! For example an asynchronous list item event handler. But be careful with item level permissions - you should not exceed 1000 unqiue security boundaries in a single list. See [Software boundaries and limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary) for SharePoint 2010.

Comment: If you'll have many unique permissions, you'll want to either use folders or push the items to uniquely secured lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an impersonation step within a SharePoint Designer workflow to modify permissions. You don't need to custom code, unless you have more requirements.

Comment: I am using SPD 2007 and WSS 3.0. I don't see impersonation step. Please help.

Comment: This will not work in an WSS 3.0 environment. Impersonation steps were introduced in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: I guess I have to create a workflow in Visual Studio to do this?

Comment: There are codeplex projects that may help you along the way. I can think of http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/ for example.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not a developer and cannot develop an event receiver, try to use this - http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=SmartActionPro
it can update the permissions of a list item according to column value, exactly as you need.

though, there is a limitation for lists with a large amount of items with specific permissions, so you would have to consider that before you are trying to find a way to apply the permissions.

Comment: I am using WSS 3.0. Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to do this without code, but you need [this addon](http://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/) from codeplex.

First, you can create a view and filter the view based on the value of a column.  So, for instance, if you create a column called "permissions" and set the value to 1, then you can create a view that filters on that column value.

Now that you have the right view created, you can use the addon I mentioned to show or hide that view based on which usergroup a person belongs to.  It's a wonderful addon - I wonder why Microsoft never included this functionality in the first place.